# Get shortest string in array ( list name )

Tags: list, sharepoint-addin

I am getting the list titles from my sharepoint site, I have made an app that gets "longest title name" so far, now I want to be able to get the "shortest title name" aswell, so this was my code to get the longest:

```
function onSuccess() {

    var listString;
    var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();

    var longest = "";

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
            title = currentItem.get_title();

        listString += "<br>" + title;

        if (longest.length < title.length)
            longest = title;
    }
    $('#divAllaListor').html(longest);
}
```

Now how do I do the same thing but getting the "shortest list title" instead of "the longest one"? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
function onSuccess() {

    var listString;
    var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();

    var shortest = "";

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
            title = currentItem.get_title();

       if (shortest == "") { shortest = title; }

        listString += "<br>" + title;

        if (shortest.length > title.length)
            shortest = title;
    }
    $('#divAllaListor').html(shortest);
}
```